# Get Radio button value to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to set the value of the radio to my paragraph. How can i do it with JQuery?

```
       <div id="gender" class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Miss" value="Miss" />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
               women
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Mr" value="Mr" />
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
              men
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>


       <div class="col-6">
          <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're repeating the `id="gender"` in your markup.  That is invalid html by web standards, as ids are expected to be unique.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This way no matter which element is clicked you get the value

```
    $('.form-check-input').on('click', function () {
    var value=$('input[name=gender]:checked').val();
    $('#output').text(value);
    });
```